# 502 Bad Gateway error: How to install php8.1-fpm.sock on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx

I have nginx running on my system and  php8.1 installed. But I am getting Bad Gateway problem. I found that I don’t have php8.1-fpm.sock installed on my system:

```
$ php -ver
PHP 8.1.7 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2022 12:22:31) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
@lc2530hz:/usr/bin$
```

My file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

contains information about php8.1-fpm.sock:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}
```

but I don’t have  php8.1-fpm.sock installed on my system:

I am getting the following error in the nginx’s error.log:

```
2022/06/21 18:01:39 [crit] 2058#2058: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /w3_scalar.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

Also:

```
@lc2530hz:/var/run/php$ ls
php8.1-fpm.pid
```

does not give me any information about  php8.1-fpm.sock, Kindly guide me how to install  php8.1-fpm.sock.

I found following command:

```
$ sudo apt install php php-cli php-fpm php-json php-mysql php-zip php-gd  php-mbstring    php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath
```

but I already have php installed on my system. Kindly guide me how to install  php8.1-fpm.sock on Ubuntu 18.04.

Zulfi.

@Eugen Rieck Uncommented contents of WWW.conf:

```
; pool name ('www' here)
[www]
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm = dynamic
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children = 5
; Default Value: (min_spare_servers + max_spare_servers) / 2
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Please guide me how to run php8.1-fpm.sock

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

The `.sock` pseudofile is installed with `php8.1-fpm`, which might

- not be running (unlikely, since a `.pid` file exists)
- have it's socket elsewhere (most likely)

The location of the socket is set in `/etc/php` in the pool config file, that belongs to your PHP version and application pool (most often "www")

Comment: I found that the filename is WWW.conf. I don't know how to set the location of php8.1-fpm.sock in this file. Most of the contents are commented with semicolon. I have listed the uncommented stuff above in the main thread. Please guide me how to execute php8.1-fpm.sock.

Comment: You have `listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock` in your config file, so the socket is not at `/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock` (where nginx looks for it) but at `/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock`. You need to adapt your configuration.

Comment: This is what I am getting for /run/php, lc2530hz:/run/php$ ls  gives
php8.1-fpm.pid
,   please guide me.

Comment: Obviously you haven't started the php8.1-fpm! When it starts, it creates the socket at the location given in den pool file.

Comment: I am getting error, $ sudo service php-fpm restart ,                          
Failed to restart php-fpm.service: Unit php-fpm.service not found.,              
Please guide me.

Comment: It worked: $ sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm
[sudo] password for zulfi: 
zulfi@lc2530hz:~$  , solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752633/failed-to-restart-php-fpm-service-unit-php-fpm-service-not-found